# Eclipse 4.4 suddenly stopped printing stack traces to console

Tags: java, eclipse

Ever since I've begun using eclipse, whenever an exception occured I'd get a message and a stack trace in the console, no matter if I caught the exception or not.

Now however, all of a sudden the only thing that is printed to the console is the class of the exception and a message if there is one. I haven't changed any settings manually but I did install Grep Console for eclipse.

Can I get stack traces back somehow without having to reinstall eclipse? I've looked around the preferences for compiler and debugger but haven't found anything which even remotely seems like it manipulates console stack traces.

Here's how exceptions are presented now. It's really difficult to do any sort of debugging without a stack trace now: [image: Stack trace missing]

Answer (score 2):

I know this post is old, but you have to add

-XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow

as a JVM-Option

Answer (score 0):

Go to  : Window -> Prefenrences
Find : Grep Console(search)
Disable : Grep Console

Comment: I haven't found any options to disable Grep Console, only options to modify the colors of the matches and colors of the grep view. I've uninstalled Grep Console but I still don't get full stack traces. Is there some XML or ini file I can edit to get stack traces back or do I have to reinstall eclipse?

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse just collects what your program (or the JVM if an exception is not caught) prints to System.out and System.err.

Hence it is not Eclipse but the logging environment in your own program that has changed.  Based on the output it appears to me that you have been experimenting with the logging pattern in logback (or log4j 1).  If the `%ex` conversion word is not present in the pattern, stack traces are not printed.

See http://logback.qos.ch/manual/layouts.html#conversionWord for the full list of conversion words.

Comment: I've tried changing the pattern layout without any luck. Are you sure that it's a logging issue? I've used this same patten layout and same logger before and I had a stack trace. I am not manually logging these exceptions(As in the image the exception doesn't have the same prefix as other logs) so eclipse should, and did handle them by itself. In my pattern i had a %throwable and I even tried changing the logger from log4j to logback and i still don't get stack traces. Same thing if I remove loggers and their config completely.

Comment: The simplest way to check, is to see what your program prints, when run outside of Eclipse.  If you are unfamiliar with that, the simplest approach is most likely File->Export->Runnable jar.

Comment: I've created a war and deployed it locally and I get the same result. What the... I swear I had stack traces two days ago. The only change I've made is that I installed the Grep Console plugin for eclipse.

Comment: If you get the same result _completely outside_ Eclipse, then it cannot be an eclipse problem.

Answer (score 0):

I've checked everything: call hierarchy for any hidden try-catch blocks, logger configuration, eclipse run configurations but found nothing. So as a last resort I reinstalled Eclipse and JDK for good measure, and now I've gotten full stack traces back. I have no idea what was the cause but now everything is back to normal.